# Why my primitives are drawn on top of each other instead inside each other?

Tags: xna-4.0

Im trying to draw cube primitive and axises going through it. The axises must not rotate with cube. I have no idea why it doesnt work just like that. If I remove `axises.ApplyPasses();` and call `cube.ApplyPasses();` axises go through cube however they rotate along with it.

Primitive class contains fields for PrimitiveType, VertexData, BasicEffect object etc. No math or whatever is done here.

`*.ApplyPasses();` is equal to `Effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();`

What I got:
[image]

What I'm trying to do:
[image]

Cube creation:

```
Primitive<VertexPositionColor> cube = new Primitive<VertexPositionColor>(_graphics.GraphicsDevice);
cube.VertexOffset = 0;
cube.Type = PrimitiveType.TriangleList;
cube.VertexData = new VertexPositionColor[]
{
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Red),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Red),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Red),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Red),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Red),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Red),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Green),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Green),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Green),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Green),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Green),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Green),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.White),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.White),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.White),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.White),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.White),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.White),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.White),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.White),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.White),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Blue),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Blue),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Blue),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Blue),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Blue),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Blue),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Black),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Black),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Black),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Black),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Black),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Black),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Black),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Black),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Black),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Yellow),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Yellow),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Yellow),

    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Yellow),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f), Color.Yellow),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), Color.Yellow)
};

cubeMatrixes = new Matrixes();
cubeMatrixes.World = Matrix.Identity;
cubeMatrixes.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
cubeMatrixes.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(110.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.001f, 10000.0f);
```

Axises creation:

```
Primitive<VertexPositionColor> axises = new Primitive<VertexPositionColor>(_graphics.GraphicsDevice);
axises.Type = PrimitiveType.LineList;
axises.VertexOffset = 0;
axises.VertexData = new VertexPositionColor[]
{
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-5, 0, 0), Color.Red),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(5, 0, 0), Color.Red),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, -5, 0), Color.Green),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 5, 0), Color.Green),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, -5), Color.Blue),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 5), Color.Blue),
};

axisesMatrixes = new Matrixes();
axisesMatrixes.World = Matrix.Identity;
axisesMatrixes.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 5.0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
axisesMatrixes.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.001f, 10000.0f);
```

Translating:

```
cube.Effect.World
    = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cubeAngle.X))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cubeAngle.Y))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(cubeAngle.Z))
    * cubeMatrixes.World;
cube.Effect.View = cubeMatrixes.View;
cube.Effect.Projection = cubeMatrixes.Projection;

axises.Effect.World
    = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(0.0f))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(-60.0f))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(0.0f))
    * axisesMatrixes.World;
axises.Effect.View
    = axisesMatrixes.View;
axises.Effect.Projection
    = axisesMatrixes.Projection;
```

Drawing:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    axises.ApplyPasses();
    _graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(axises.Type, axises.VertexData, axises.VertexOffset, axises.Count);

    cube.ApplyPasses();
    _graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(cube.Type, cube.VertexData, cube.VertexOffset, cube.Count);     

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answear to this question is that I created separate projection matrixes.

When changed to single projection matrix for both axisses and cube everything worked as expected.

Translating:

```
cube.Effect.World
    = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cubeAngle.X))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cubeAngle.Y))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(cubeAngle.Z))
    * cubeMatrixes.World;
cube.Effect.View = cubeMatrixes.View;
cube.Effect.Projection = cubeMatrixes.Projection;

axises.Effect.World
    = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(0.0f))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(-60.0f))
    * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(0.0f))
    * axisesMatrixes.World;
axises.Effect.View
    = axisesMatrixes.View;
axises.Effect.Projection
    = cubeMatrixes.Projection; // instead axisesMatrixes.Projection;
```